# GARCH(1,1)modelling with two specifications using RUGARCH in R

Tags: r, garch

I am trying to fit GARCH(1,1) with different specifications using rugarch package in R.

I study on two models:

model 1 : $\sigma$<sup>2</sup><sub>t</sub>
=$\omega$
+$\beta\sigma$<sup>2</sup><sub>t-1</sub>
+$\alpha$r<sup>2</sup><sub>t-1</sub>

model 2 : $\sigma$<sup>2</sup><sub>t</sub>
=$\omega$
+$\beta\sigma$<sup>2</sup><sub>t-1</sub>
+$\theta$x<sub>t-1</sub>

Two models above volatility models with different specifications where

- r<sub>t</sub> denotes return at time t
- x<sub>t</sub> denotes an exogeneous variable at time t

I let to be x<sub>t</sub>=r<sub>t</sub><sup>2</sup> . So two models are exactly the same. So I wait same results from these two models.

I use rugarch library for GARCH modelling.

The data is as below where x is just one lag shift of r. The series are in date increasing order(Namely, first row's variables belong to  the oldest date and last row's are the closest date)

```
                      r            x
  [1,]  0.011669346 -0.032336056
  [2,] -0.006983248  0.011669346
  [3,]  0.016220673 -0.006983248
  [4,]  0.013700523  0.016220673
  [5,]  0.002263663  0.013700523
  [6,] -0.032184859  0.002263663
  [7,] -0.009391728 -0.032184859
  [8,] -0.009478213 -0.009391728
  [9,] -0.002382376 -0.009478213
 [10,] -0.014425089 -0.002382376
 [11,]  0.016807465 -0.014425089
 [12,]  0.002379264  0.016807465
 [13,]  0.041866672  0.002379264
 [14,] -0.027716299  0.041866672
 [15,] -0.004694578 -0.027716299
 [16,] -0.004716721 -0.004694578
 [17,] -0.016687248 -0.004716721
 [18,]  0.002399538 -0.016687248
 [19,]  0.021353215  0.002399538
 [20,]  0.013987957  0.021353215
 [21,]  0.006918815  0.013987957
 [22,]  0.013700523  0.006918815
 [23,]  0.004524636  0.013700523
 [24,] -0.013638250  0.004524636
 [25,] -0.039677525 -0.013638250
 [26,]  0.009478213 -0.039677525
 [27,]  0.007051424  0.009478213
 [28,] -0.011779301  0.007051424
 [29,] -0.004750336 -0.011779301
 [30,] -0.004773010 -0.004750336
 [31,]  0.004773010 -0.004773010
 [32,] -0.026539355  0.004773010
 [33,]  0.014562548 -0.026539355
 [34,]  0.004807435  0.014562548
 [35,] -0.069505654  0.004807435
 [36,]  0.030383068 -0.069505654
 [37,] -0.002498078  0.030383068
 [38,]  0.009949773 -0.002498078
 [39,]  0.031670891  0.009949773
 [40,]  0.023699009  0.031670891
 [41,]  0.011642163  0.023699009
 [42,]  0.009216131  0.011642163
 [43,] -0.009216131  0.009216131
 [44,] -0.009301859 -0.009216131
 [45,]  0.004661745 -0.009301859
 [46,]  0.004640114  0.004661745
 [47,]  0.011505725  0.004640114
 [48,]  0.006842375  0.011505725
 [49,]  0.004534901  0.006842375
 [50,]  0.006765230  0.004534901
 [51,]  0.035324122  0.006765230
 [52,] -0.002172596  0.035324122
 [53,]  0.023631436 -0.002172596
 [54,] -0.019293277  0.023631436
 [55,]  0.012904984 -0.019293277
 [56,]  0.014844533  0.012904984
 [57,]  0.055285545  0.014844533
 [58,]  0.003978058  0.055285545
 [59,]  0.017697522  0.003978058
 [60,] -0.013737348  0.017697522
 [61,]  0.019568986 -0.013737348
 [62,]  0.001937039  0.019568986
 [63,] -0.019532862  0.001937039
 [64,]  0.013712542 -0.019532862
 [65,]  0.011604895  0.013712542
 [66,] -0.031250774  0.011604895
 [67,]  0.001980984 -0.031250774
 [68,]  0.005923742  0.001980984
 [69,]  0.017561472  0.005923742
 [70,] -0.015596070  0.017561472
 [71,] -0.001965402 -0.015596070
 [72,]  0.007842732 -0.001965402
 [73,]  0.005842988  0.007842732
 [74,] -0.013685720  0.005842988
 [75,]  0.011741152 -0.013685720
 [76,] -0.007812097  0.011741152
 [77,] -0.023811435 -0.007812097
 [78,] -0.047285949 -0.023811435
 [79,]  0.018770182 -0.047285949
 [80,] -0.006216175  0.018770182
 [81,]  0.002075612 -0.006216175
 [82,]  0.030647471  0.002075612
 [83,]  0.064286455  0.030647471
 [84,]  0.058625434  0.064286455
 [85,]  0.003552198  0.058625434
 [86,]  0.003539625  0.003552198
 [87,] -0.005315100  0.003539625
 [88,] -0.017920609 -0.005315100
 [89,] -0.001810824 -0.017920609
 [90,]  0.012601681 -0.001810824
 [91,]  0.003571230  0.012601681
 [92,]  0.024649628  0.003571230
 [93,] -0.026434607  0.024649628
 [94,]  0.007118977 -0.026434607
 [95,]  0.008824738  0.007118977
 [96,]  0.024307257  0.008824738
 [97,] -0.003436236  0.024307257
 [98,]  0.023811127 -0.003436236
 [99,] -0.008439297  0.023811127
[100,]  0.003383907 -0.008439297
```

And my model speficatiosn are as below:

```
spec1=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH"),
                 garchOrder = c(1, 1),
                 mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)))
fit1=ugarchfit(data=r,spec=spec1)


spec2=ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH",
                                     garchOrder = c(0, 1),
                                     external.regressors =as.matrix(x^2) ),
                 mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)))
fit2=ugarchfit(data=r,spec=spec2)
```

I get the below coefficients:

```
> fit1@fit$matcoef
           Estimate   Std. Error      t value  Pr(>|t|)
mu     3.234597e-03 2.017993e-03 1.602878e+00 0.1089615
omega  7.976922e-07 3.611139e-06 2.208977e-01 0.8251721
alpha1 5.720129e-10 1.005801e-02 5.687136e-08 1.0000000
beta1  9.989994e-01 9.355419e-03 1.067830e+02 0.0000000
> fit2@fit$matcoef
           Estimate   Std. Error      t value  Pr(>|t|)
mu     3.233113e-03 2.011659e-03 1.607187e+00 0.1080133
omega  3.852221e-07 2.970305e-06 1.296911e-01 0.8968108
beta1  9.999978e-01 4.888330e-03 2.045684e+02 0.0000000
vxreg1 8.056529e-10 5.450382e-03 1.478159e-07 0.9999999
```

The results are close but not exacty same. What makes the difference?

- Do I think wrong about to get the same results?(why?)
- Do I make any mistake while defining the models in R?(where?)
- Is it natural to get different results?(why?)

I guess it is about initial values. But I can't figure it out exactly.

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the future, you can benefit from writing equations in the classic TeX way, with underscores for subsripts etc. That will be faster to type and more elegant to look at. Something like $\sigma_t^2=\omega+\beta \sigma_{t-1}^2+\alpha r_{t-1}^2$ can be typed as `\sigma_t^2=\omega+\beta \sigma_{t-1}^2+\alpha r_{t-1}^2` (with a dollar symbol before the expression and another right after it).

Comment: Have you tried using the same initial values in both cases? That should be technically possible.

Comment: I coudn't figure out how to implement initial values to the model in RUGARCH. I think impelemnting it will make clear the problem.